# RAII and unit testing principles

Tags: unit-testing, raii, design-principles, tradeoff

The RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization) is one of the suggested ways of constructing objects. How does it relate to the unit testing principles that are saying: no complex job done in the constructor? And especially no explicit creation of objects by "new" operator? However creation of some objects requires some more complex steps sometimes, and passing a factory to a constructor makes the API "dirty" in the meaning of decreasing the legibility. What are the general ways of meeting both of the principles at the same time?

I have found the other topic on SO: [Stack allocated RAII objects vs DI principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806985/stack-allocated-raii-objects-vs-di-principle), however it looks like a more general problem and it is not explained well.

Comment: @MartinJames why? It sounds like a legitimate software design question to me. Moreover, I can't think of any class that'd ask this as homework.

Comment: If this is an assignment question then I want to study there! However it's an issue that I meet in every day work. I would like to meet the opinions and the ways the other developers handle it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, creating a concrete class in a constructor complicates the class that does so, adds a dependency to the class, and makes it harder to test.

But, RAII isn't a way of constructing objects, but of releasing resources. The class whose destructor releases the resource doesn't have to construct the object, although it usually does: see [What is meant by Resource Acquisition is Initialization (RAII)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii).

So, create the resource outside the class that uses it if you want, use a factory to do so if you want, etc., but then let the class that uses the resource clean it up with RAII.

Comment: Actually at certain moment I have regreted I asked this question as the perfect example of such behaviour is shared_ptr.